# How to group Datatable by multiple columns into another Datatable without using Linq in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, datatable

How to group Datatable by multiple columns into another Datatable without using Linq in vb.net ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us an example of exactly what your asking?

Answer (score 0):

2 DataTables: tab1 & tab2...
tab1 has columns that tab2 dowsn't contains...

```
For Each col As DataColumn In tab1.Columns
    If Not tab2.Columns.Contains(col.ColumnName) Then
        tab2.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName)
    End If
Next
```

This add to tab2 the columns of tab1 that tab2 don't contain...

You want this or you want to copy the data from one table to another where the first has n columns and the second n + x?